# Creating a new variable in a logistic regression

Tags: r

I am trying to create a logistic regression predicting what restaurant is more closely linked to some nutritional variables. I am using the fastfood dataset from openintro.  Below is my code. I am getting inaccurate numbers for the coefficients.  McDonalds should be 1, Subway should be 0. I think the problem might be in the `mutate` line of code, but am not sure.  Can someone take a look?

```
rest<-fastfood%>%
  filter(restaurant=="McDonalds" | restaurant=="Subway")%>%
  mutate(restbin=ifelse(restaurant=="Subway",0,1))
log<-glm(restbin~calories+sodium+protein,binomial(),data=rest)
round(log$coefficients,2)
```

Comment: what do you get when you `table(rest$restaurant, rest$restbin, useNA ="ifany")` if it is perfectly separated then there wasn't an issue with the mutate.

Comment: and what do you mean by inaccurate?

Comment: Here is the result of your code check:              `0
                                                                  Subway 96`

Comment: Sorry my original comment got cut off.Here is the result of your code check: `0 Subway 96`  MCDs appears to be missing, so it does appear that something is wrong.  Expected output is supposed to be intercept:-1.24, calories: 0.00 sodium: 0.00 protein: 0.06

Comment: the 'D' in McDonalds needs to be lower cased, you can use `unique(fastfood$restaurant)` to see the exact spelling of each restaurant